# logback via slf4j as separate osgi bundle

Tags: maven, logging, osgi, slf4j, apache-karaf

We have `osgi` application in `karaf` and want to have logging properties inside bundle jar to keep the logging config in sources (currently they are in `karaf/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg`)

UPDATE: in fact now we keep log configs in Karaf CM Admin service, and it's a problem because on each release we should write special instructions to our operation team to make any tiny logging change. Moreover we have multiple karaf nodes (~10) and repeating these actions for each is a complex and error-prone task. Sure we can intall `Cellar` to each karaf node but it will complicate the osgi env and require some support for it, so the simplest way just to keep config in the sources

I've googled that [easiest way to create a separate bundle](http://blog.kornr.net/index.php/2008/12/18/osgi-logging-putting-it-all-together#c115) with does actual logging stuff with all dependencies (logback, slf4j, config) inside and just export `org.slf4` from them.

I tried with this `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <unpackBundle>true</unpackBundle>
                <instructions>
                    <Embed-Dependency>*;groupId=!junit|org.springframework|log4j|javax.jms|javax.mail</Embed-Dependency>
                    <Embed-Transitive>false</Embed-Transitive>
                    <Embed-Directory>target/dependency</Embed-Directory>
                    <Embed-StripGroup>true</Embed-StripGroup>
                    <Export-Package>org.slf4j</Export-Package>
                    <Import-Package>
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.springframework,log4j</excludeGroupIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.ch.qos.logback.classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.ch.qos.logback.core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

but it puts to bundle manifest a lot of additional dependecies like `javax.mail/jms` etc:

```
Import-Package: javax.jms,javax.mail,javax.mail.internet,javax.management,javax.naming,javax.servlet,javax.servlet.http,javax.sql,javax.xml.parsers,org.codehaus.janino,org.slf4j;version="1.6",org.xml.sax,org.xml.sax.helpers,sun.reflect
```

sure it's not a good approach to deploy all this unnecessary stuff to karaf in order to resolve them.

What's wrong or how to build a single bundle with all logging dependencies inside?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think there is a need to create such a bundle. Pax Logging [receives its configuration via the Configuration Admin Service](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/logging/reference/configuration.html). Thus you can update that configuration from any of your bundles. No repackaging required.

Comment: exactly, and as I wrote we already have all log configs in `karaf/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg`, i.e. karaf Conf Admin Service and it's a problem because on each release we should write special instructions to our operation team to make any tiny logging change. Moreover we have multiple karaf nodes (~10) and repeating it for each is a huge task. Sure they can do it once after intalling `Cellar` to each karaf node but it will complicate the osgi env and require to support cellar on each node also

Answer (score 0):

Just create a bundle with the configuration data in it on a well specified place (e.g. a JSON file in /configuration/configuration.json). Then make an extender that reads this data when the bundle is changed and updates configuration admin.

I've written such an extender, you can find it http://jpm4j.org/#!/p/osgi/aQute.configurer?tab=readme

Source code is included in the JAR: http://repo.jpm4j.org/rest/bundle/51C83986E4B06EF1574B84F7/c9256d19f155d699ed0d18559bbb80441ac68ff7